# Bootstrap automatically inserting tag <a href="#"></a>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am creating a navbar for a project using bootstrap. I am seeing a randomly generated `<a>` block when I run the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I see the number 1 is lower than the rest, and when using inspect element from chrome, I see the code as:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"when I run the following code"_.  One doesn't "run" HTML.

Comment: showalso the code preceding this code

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't randomly insert code on its own. You should also post the CSS being applied. Also, what is the purpose of the jsp tag on this question?

Comment: It's possible there is an error in the code somewhere else in this html file. Maybe an unclosed tag.